# Button to pass informations to php form without submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a html/js page with a php form; it contains products in different carousels ( https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2 )

Every slide of these carousels contains an image and a button;
I'm trying to pass to the form the "selected product" from the carousel, in order to get this information in the mail received from the form;

**so basically: how can I pass a value to a form, from outside the "form" tag?**
Tried different solutions with no luck;
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can start the form tag before the carousel slider and then pass the values where ever you want. Your program will still work. e.g.

```
<form>
    <carousel slider code here >
    <button codes here>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your requirement, you should create a jQuery event when your form get submitted. When your form submits, you need to get image from carousel and then set that image in your form(you can create a hidden element in your form). Like this:

```
<form action="submit.php" id="addForm">
    <input type="hidden" id="carousel_image" name="carousel_image" value=""/>
    /* other fields here */
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"/>
</form>
```

in jQuery:

```
$( "#addForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
    $("#carousel_image").val('here you need to get image path or id');  
});
```

Hope it helps you.